# Hide all on sale products on WooCommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide all sale products on a static wordpress site, where a WooCommerce Product widget is placed. Is there any way to achieve that?

The reason behind it is, that i want 2 category pages for each brand. 1 Sale Products, 1 Regular Products.

I tried following code but it didn't work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'on_sale_products_not_in_archives', 10, 2 );
function on_sale_products_not_in_archives( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // For woocommerce shop pages
    if( is_shop() ){
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => '_sale_price',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear… Do you want to filter the products from a widget? or do you want to filter the products from specific archive pages or from a custom page? Please edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()` core function in a product query, like:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'not_on_sale_products_product_query' );
function not_on_sale_products_product_query( $q ) {
    // On product archive pages only
    if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) {
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', array_merge( array( 0 ), wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() ) );
    }
}
```

**But for a products widget** you should try to use instead:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', 'not_on_sale_products_widget_query_args' );
function not_on_sale_products_widget_query_args( $query_args ) {
    // On product archive pages only
    if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) {
        $query_args['post__not_in'] = array_merge( array( 0 ), wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It could work

Related: [Get WooCommerce onSale products on Archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76967428/get-woocommerce-onsale-products-on-archives/76967798#76967798)